# Find the values a and b such that the function is differentiable

Tags: functions, differential

$f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+e^{(1/x)})}$ for $x<0$ and $ax^2+b$ for $x\geq 0$

so I know that if function is differentable at some point $x=0$ for piecewise functions their

limits have to be equal but im confused about this $e^{(1/x)}$ because you cant divide by $0$ and im not sure what to do

Comment: *Hint:* $e^{1/x}$ is *very very small* for negative $x$ close to zero.

Comment: What are you confused about? There is no division by $0$ because the formula where you see $e^{1/x}$ only holds for $x < 0$. When $x = 0, f(x) = ax^3 + b$. That is, $f(0) = b$. When you take the derivative from *either* side, that is the value of $f(0)$ in the difference quotient. But before you worry about whether $f$ is differentiable, you should worry first about whether it is even continuous, because $f$ cannot be differentiable at $0$ if it is not continuous there.